# Making the background transparent but not the text box and etc

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make the form background transparent. But not other elements.
How do I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the form's TransparencyKey equal to the form's color.

There's a good tutorial [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/XparentFormsCS10282007212944PM/XparentFormsCS.aspx), detailing how to make a transparent splash screen.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the transparency key equal to the background color. For example:

```
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.Black;
        this.BackColor = Color.Black;
```